# How to edit the default robots.txt file in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, robots.txt, prestashop-1.6

I identified that a certain line in the robots.txt that prestashop automatically generates is blocking our products from Google Shopping.

the line in question is

```
Disallow: /*n=
```

The matched URL has some UTM tracking parameters used by Google Analytics. Example URL that matches the line in robots.txt:

domain.com/page.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=shopping

the part that matches is the **`n=`** in **`utm_campaign=`**

I'm trying to get FTP access and will able to edit the robots.txt manually, but I noticed that in the back-end there's a button to automatically generate it again, so I'm afraid that someone might go in there, re-generate it and then we have to do the same thing over again... Is there a fail safe way to edit what goes into the default robots.txt file?

Comment: If all else fails, you might hand-edit the file, then set permissions to read-only. I would only do this as a last resort, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line in your `robots.txt`

```
Allow: /*campaign=
```